# What's the difference between using id="mydiv" and #mydiv in Angular HTML?

Tags: html, angular

It's a simple Angular HTML question, I would like a bit clarity about the id of tags. For example, in my code I have:

```
    <input class="inputfile" type="file" name="file" #file id="file" 
    (change)="onFileChange($event)"/>

    <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="file.click()">                        
            <mat-icon aria-label="Icon to upload file">cloud_upload</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <label for="file" >Upload your portifolio</label>
```

In that example, I had to **set `#file` in the input for the button to work and also had to set `id="file"` for the label to work**. Previously I thought they had the same function and it was just about syntax. Could someone clarify what are the uses of each?

Comment: `#file` in angular is not the same `#` in css. `#` is used for referencing a template variable that can be hooked up in the `.ts` file. refer [this](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-a-template-reference-variable)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to identify an element using javascript function or from your controller using getElementByID or to point to a style in a style sheet, you need to set the `id` that has to that element be unique throughout your DOM.

However, when you want to access your element within the DOM file you need to refer the element using `#`. if you use just `id` you will have the error `Cannot read property 'XXX' of undefined` in your browser.

For example, in order to show/hide a button using the value of an input in DOM file without writing any javascript/angular code you could do something like the following, in which setting the `id` wouldn't work out.

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input #nameField matInput placeholder="Name">
  </mat-form-field>

  <button type="button" *ngIf="nameField.value!==''" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Reference to [this](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-a-template-reference-variable) to dealing with user input and [this](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) as a broader explanation of the # tag.

Answer (score 3):

In an Angular application `#mydiv` can have different functions depending on the context.

- On a DOM element `<div #mydiv>` is a reference to the element
- A reference to an Angular component
- On an element that is an Angular component, or has an Angular directive, where `exportas:"ngform"` is defined, `#mydiv="ngForm"` creates a component reference.

Answer (score -2):

*id* in html used to assign unique mark for element (later can be used by javascript). *#* in html used as mark on this element (like link to this element). Example:you have pressed button and browser scrolls to that element marked with *#file*.